# Force a specific version param when packing a nuget in TFS build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to setup a TFS build to publish a nuget version using a different version than the one specified by the build number (I use a string for the build definition name in the build number format and would like to keep it this way).

I'm passing *-version $(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).$(Rev:rr)* to the Packager step, but it fails with this message:

Attempting to build package from 'MyProj.Contracts.nuspec'.

```
[error]'$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).$(Rev:rr)' is not a valid version string.
[error]Parameter name: version
[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Those version strings are not available in the build itself as variables. But if you've made them part of the `Build.BuildNumber` value, you can extract the version part from it using a bit of powershell or using my [VSTS Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks):

[image]

Then use that `$(Nuget.VersionNumber)` for your Nuget package task.